# Why + operator create a new list but += not

Tags: python, list

```
>>> List1 = [1,2,3,4,5]  #Normal List
>>> list2 = list1        
>>> list1 is list2       #list2 is also pointing to the same location as list1
True
```

But when we use + operator it creates a new list

```
>>> list2 = list2 + [5]  #adding a list to list2
>>> list1 is list2       #list1 is not pointing to the same location as list2
False
>>> list2                #list2 is modified
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]
>>> list1                #but list1 is same as before
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

But when we use += operator it doesn't create a new list

```
>>> list2 += [5]         #adding a list to list2
>>> list1 is list2       #list1 is pointing to the same location as list2
True
>>> list2                #list2 is modified
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]
>>> list1                #list1 is also modified
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]
```

Why there is different behavior for the same operation.

Comment: It's not clear to me what question you're asking. This happens because `__add__` (`+`) and `__iadd__` (`+=`) are two separate methods with different behaviour, they are **not** the same operation. `+=` behaves like `.extend`. Or are you asking about the language design aspect?

Comment: I am just confused a += b and a = a + b both are doing the same thing but why it is showing different behavior for a list.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "different behavior for the same operation"? You are using two *different* operations, `+` and `+=`. Different operations (usually) have different behavior, that's why they are different operations.

Comment: thanks @jonrsharpe

Comment: @JörgWMittag actually i am from c background where a = a+b; and a+=b; are the same operation.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 my downvote was because the initial question featured screenshots of code, which has since been removed, along with my downvote.

Comment: By default, `a += b` is indeed `a = a + b`. Classes can override this behaviour by defining the method `__iadd__`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a = b + c` means "set `a` to `b` plus `c`". `a += b` means "add `b` to `a`". With the first one, `b + c` just means "`b` plus `c`"; they are added together to form a new list representing the idea of `b + c`. But in the second, `b` is added to `a`; `b` is changed by this.

This conceptual difference is reflected in the different methods called; `__add__` for the former and `__iadd__` for the latter.

Comment: its not a = b + c it is a = a + b

Comment: @tarunsharma967 Renaming the variables doesn't make a difference. `x + y` creates a new list, always.